# How do I take an image that is plotted as a result of a function call and plot to a grid of images?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, multiple-axes

I have a function that I use to output a photo that has had its pixels clustered using KMeans. I can input the k value as an argument, and it will fit the model and output the new image.

```
def cluster_image(k, img=img):
  img_flat = img.reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state = 42).fit(img_flat)
  new_img = img_flat.copy()
  
  for i in np.unique(kmeans.labels_):
    new_img[kmeans.labels_ == i, :] = kmeans.cluster_centers_[i]
  
  new_img = new_img.reshape(img.shape)

  return plt.imshow(new_img), plt.axis('off');
```

I want to write a loop to output the images for k=2 through k=10:

```
k_values = np.arange(2, 11)
for k in k_values:
  print('k = ' + str(k))
  cluster_image(k)
  show()
```

This returns a vertical line of images. How do I do something like this, but output each image to a 3x3 grid of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to modify the signature of `cluster_image`, I would do:

```py
def cluster_image(k, ax, img=img):
    img_flat = img.reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state = 42).fit(img_flat)
    new_img = img_flat.copy()

    for i in np.unique(kmeans.labels_):
        new_img[kmeans.labels_ == i, :] = kmeans.cluster_centers_[i]

    new_img = new_img.reshape(img.shape)
    ax.imshow(new_img)
    ax.axis('off')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3)
axs = axs.flatten()
k_values = np.arange(2, 11)
for i, k in enumerate(k_values):
    print('k = ' + str(k))
    cluster_image(k, axs[i], img=img)
```